# Patching Holes in Iron Staircase

Tags: outdoor, stairs, patch, welding, cast-iron

My condo building has an outdoor iron staircase that has been developing some penny to quarter sized holes. While the staircase is structurally sound, I’m looking for a solution to patch the holes in order to ease the concerns of some residents looking to avoid harm.

I’ve read that iron can be devilishly difficult to    weld. I’m pretty hands on, and I’m ideally looking for a DIY solution, but I'm hoping to draw on the experience and recommendations of the community. Here's some pictures for reference:

[image: Holes #1]

[image: Iron Staircase]

[image: Holes #3]

[image: Holes #4]

Answer (score 1):

Do not waste your time. Salt got to it and needs to be replaced. Do one step at a time. band-aid just waste of money and time. Metal grate may be better. No snow and less salt. Check on grate high heels may be problem. And not code in area.

Comment: As in replace one step at a time, rather than the whole staircase at once?

Comment: Yes that was in main answer someone edited it.One at a time .

Comment: If you can metal grate may be better ,snow stays off and stays clean .

Comment: Does it go over doorway as roof?

Comment: No - There’s another (concrete) stairwell underneath it, leading down to a basement door. It’s probably 12 feet down at the lowest point. But the lower stairwell is locked-off and rarely used.

Comment: Junk could fall through.

Comment: Yes, especially considering it leads out to the trash area. Junk still gets through today via gaps between the metal steps.